# Converting pointers in nested structs to offsets programmatically

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, struct

This is a very specific question, and I am almost entirely sure it's not possible, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

I have some structs that looks like this:

```
struct ParentStruct
{
  int valueA;
  const ChildStruct *pointerB;
  const AnotherChildStruct *pointerC;
}

struct ChildStruct
{
  int valueB;
  float valueC;
  const AnotherChildStruct *pointerD;
}

struct AnotherChildStruct
{
  float valueD;
  const ChildStruct *pointerE;
}
```

These structs can, in later revisions, become quite large, nesting other structs within them. The only guarantee is that all these structs will be aggregates, and all of these structs will reside in a singular block of contiguous memory.

In order to make `ParentStruct` trivially copiable, I would like to convert all pointers within an instance of `ParentStruct` and any pointers referenced to by any children of `ParentStruct (And indeed any children of those) to *offsets* from the address of struct, and then be able to convert those offsets back to pointers.

This means doing a depth first scan of every member of the struct in the style of this pseudocode:

```
template <typename T>
{
void serialize(T const& X, byte& origin)
{
  //scan through every member of X
  for(auto member : X)
  {
    if(is_pointer(member))
    {
      serialize<type_of(member) const&>(&member, origin);
      member = ((byte*) member) - origin;
    }
  }
}
}
```

And vice-versa.

How would I implement the above pseudo-code?

Comment: Your _very specific question_ appears to be missing the _question_ part.

Comment: Is it possible to modify your structures to always work with array indices instead of pointers? That way you don't need a special serialising function which needs to have knowledge of every pointer member and you can add as many of these indices as you like without needing equivalent serialising/deserialising code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious added a question

Comment: @PaulHK I think it would be valid to express this kind of structure with index offsets rather than pointers- However, structs would allow for easier code maintainability and more readability when using said data structures.

Comment: You would still use structs, just your pointers inside them becomes indices.  I get what you're saying about losing readability. Maybe an alternative would be to encode an ID or index member into every struct you're pointing to? Then your serialiser can map these.